# Install location system apps

Tags: android

I have been building a custom ROM and I added some pre-build apk's to this ROM.
When I actually flash the ROM I do see that those new "system apps" are preinstalled.
Still I was wondering about the location of the installation?

When I search on the net everyone actually refers to /system/apps/ as the location, and yes the precompiled .apk files are there. Still it's just an apk, a compressed file not an installed app.

Normally when I install an app it's resources/files are placed under /data/data. 
So now I would like to know where a pre-build system app gets installed?

In my specific example I actually ship some binaries and some scripts (as assets) with my app, which when being installed as a non-system app, can simply be found under /data/data/my.app.name/bin

The funny thing is that when I start the app after it has been supplied as a system app in my ROM it will actually be able to see the supplied script files, yet when I search for those I cannot find them!

Just curious if anyone knows how a system app installation actually works, what are the performed actions, why can I only find the .apk and not the "decompressed" installation directory?

Comment: It's a bit Off-Topic here but when you put something under `/system/apps` it gets installed automatically after next reboot.. In your case it will be installed in the first boot. But the needed data and cache won't be created until application exclusively wants that (It get's launched for the first time). The installation won't create the needed data. That is the behavior of android

Comment: Wall of text, and really off topic.\

Comment: well you are mentioning it gets installed automatically after next reboot, do you also know where ?